# PHP If entire word is within string

Tags: php

How would i go about checking if an ENTIRE word is present within a string in php? I've found a few answere here on StackOverFlow:

```
if (preg_match($needle, $haystack))
```

another way:

```
if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false)
```

Both of these methods work to a certain extent, BUT these methods will also return true if `$haystack` includes only a portion of `$needle`, which is a problem..

For example if i try to check if `$haystack` contains the word "PartialWord" BUT i make `$needle` equal to "Partial"

```
$needle = "Partial";
$haystack = "PartialWord-random)exampletextfoo-blabla";
if (preg_match($needle, $haystack))
```

it will return true even though it should return false because `$needle` is equal to "Partial" & for it to return true `$needle` should be equal to "PartialWord".

Any suggestions?

Comment: But your strign *does* contain "Partial" do you mean that you want to search for (something that constitutes a word break, like punctuation, whitespace etc.) then your needle, and then (something that constitutes a word break, like punctuation, whitespace etc.) instead? (In which case, look again at `preg_match`, but change the search expression)

Comment: You have really loosened the definition of word here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match('/\b(express\w+)\b/', $needle, $haystack); // matches expression
preg_match('/\b(\w*form\w*)\b/', $needle, $haystack); // matches perform,
                                                     // formation, unformatted
```

Where:

```
\b is a word boundary
\w+ is one or more "word" character*
\w* is zero or more "word" characters
```

See the manual on [escape sequences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) for PCRE.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be:

```
$words= preg_split("/\W/", $haystack);
return in_array($needle, $words);
```

Where `\W` is any non-word character.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution is to use preg_match

```
If (preg_match("/\s" . $SearchWord . "\s/", $haystack)){
      Echo "found";
}else{
      Echo "not found";
}
```

It will look for `$SearchWord` with a space on each side, which is as far as I know the definition of word.
So in your case it wil not match Partial of Partialword since there is no space in Partialword.